# form anchor / dock

Tags: c#, wpf, anchor

Ok this may sound as if I didn't do any research but I did. I have this form:

[image]

and I want to use it for any amount of players I want by dynamically adding labels and textboxes which was OK. However I find that space in the middle very tedious. How can I set the components to be sort of packed depending on how many components I have. I remember using Java, there was a method to pack components but there seems to be no such thing in C#. I researched about anchor and dock but I'm hoping maybe there is a simpler way?

If not, how do you suggest I do this please?

Comment: What kind of forms? WPF?

Comment: It's really a very big difference. If you're using WPF, then use the [tag:wpf] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a class that holdst properties like "PlayerNo" (Int32) and "PlayerName" (String).
Let's call the class "PlayerInfo".

Secondly I would create an ObservableCollection of PlayerInfo and add the number of players there.
Let's call it Players. I would create Dependency Property for all properties so I can use my classes in XAML, and inegrit INotifyPropertyChanged so the UI updates automatically.

```
this.Players = new ObservableCollection<PlayerInfo>();
this.Players.Add(new PlayerInfo() { PlayerNo=0, PlayerName=null });
this.Players.Add(new PlayerInfo() { PlayerNo=1, PlayerName=null });
this.Players.Add(new PlayerInfo() { PlayerNo=2, PlayerName=null });
```

Then I would create an ItemsPresenter control in the XAML that has a binding from the ItemsSource to the Players property in the model class. You can even fill "PlayerName" and more based on the players of the previous round etc etc. I have illustrated it by setting it to "null" (which of course is not necessary, only illustrative)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Players, Mode=OneWay}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="Player" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PlayerNo, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="10,0,20,0" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PlayerName, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="200" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

For the ItemsPresenter class, I would create a ItemTemplate that holds a TextBlock that is showing "Player" followed by the "PlayerId" number. And I would use a TextBox that has a binding from the Text property to the item's "PlayerName" property.

This way, I would have little codebehind and little XAML. It's an easy solution.
And I would also have the player details all ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (maybe is not included in your Visual Studio toolbox by default, but you can add it manually). For example, your XAML code could be something like this:

```
<UniformGrid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="uniformGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" Columns="1" />
```

And the code to add controls to the *UniformGrid* would be:

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Width = 100;
tb.Height = 26;
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Content = "Player:";
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
Canvas.SetLeft(lbl, 10);
Canvas.SetTop(lbl, 5);
Canvas.SetLeft(tb, 60);
Canvas.SetTop(tb, 5);
canvas.Children.Add(lbl);
canvas.Children.Add(tb);
uniformGrid1.Children.Add(canvas);
```

By the way, I think your font color should be white (or other with a better contrast).